# functions in coffee-file are not available from other js

Tags: grails, coffeescript, scope, coffeescript-resources

I try to use coffeescript in my Grails-project. To achive this I decided to use coffeescript-resources plugin. But compiled coffee in result view looks like follows:

```
(function() {
    var someFunc;
    someFunc = function() {
       return alert("hello");
    };
}).call(this);
```

and in this case I cant call it. I have not found any proper configurations in the plugin documentation to avoid using anonymous functions while compiling coffee-file. How can I solve this?

Comment: there is a pull-request for this feature (`--bare`), and for many other things, but plugin author stopped working on it. So, I recommend you to use standalone command line compile for coffeescript instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#lexical-scope):

> **Lexical Scoping and Variable Safety**
>   [...]
>   Although suppressed within this documentation for clarity, all CoffeeScript output is wrapped in an anonymous function:  `(function(){ ... })();` This safety wrapper, combined with the automatic generation of the `var` keyword, make it exceedingly difficult to pollute the global namespace by accident.
>
> If you'd like to create top-level variables for other scripts to use, attach them as properties on **window**, or on the **exports** object in CommonJS. The **existential operator** (covered below), gives you a reliable way to figure out where to add them; if you're targeting both CommonJS and the browser: `exports ? this`

So that self-invoking function wrapper exists to prevent you from polluting the global namespace. If you want to put something into the global namespace then you have to put it there explicitly; in a browser, you can do that using:

```
window.someFunc = -> alert('hello')
```

or

```
@someFunc = -> alert('hello')
```

The `@someFunc` form assumes that you're at the top of the scope (i.e. not inside another function or class).

Alternatively, you could find a way to compile your CoffeeScript with [`--bare`](http://coffeescript.org/#usage):

> `-b, --bare`
>   Compile the JavaScript without the *top-level function safety wrapper*.

Comment: PS: If anyone can find the canonical answer for this question, let me know and I'll delete this answer and mark the question as a duplicate. My search-fu seems to be weak this morning.

Comment: Thank you very much! Decided to attach functions to the window

Comment: That's generally a better idea than depending on `--bare` being used in the build process.